# Нужно ли двоеточие в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Правильно ли построено предложение? Нужны ли двоеточия, выделенные в скобках?

Чего я хочу от себя завтра?(:)
-Это как минимум (:) навести уборку в комнате, прогуляться на улице, навестить дедушку

Answer (score 1):

**В качестве варианта:**

*Чего я хочу от себя завтра? Это, **как минимум,**  навести уборку в комнате, прогуляться на улице, навестить дедушку.*

Наречие ***как минимум*** обособляется при необходимости, и здесь обособление желательно. В этом случае двоеточие **не нужно,** а указательное местоимение  ***это*** будет относиться непосредственно к однородному ряду.

**[Справочник по пунктуации.](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/kak-minimum)**